# Issue with filtering Data fetched from sanity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am working on a React App, and currently having an Issue when trying to filter Data i fetch from sanity.

Overall it is pretty simple,
Data is being fetched, on Page load (no filter active) all of the data should be shown
-> when e.g. tag is clicked, only data containing the value of the clicked tag should be shown.

Filter functionality actually works, the only problem i have is that none objects are shown on Page load. As soon as i click on a "filter-tag" the according data is returned.

I already got this to work, with a local "test"-array of objects, but since switching to sanity i am facing this problem.

Please can somebody help me out, probably i am overseeing a small mistake..

This is what my code looks like:

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "post"]{
      title,
      slug,
      style,
      thumbnail{
          asset->{
              url
          },
      },
      images[]{
          asset->{
            _id,
            url
          },
          alt
        },
      "categories": categories[]->title 
    }`)
      .then((data) => setPost(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  const [postData, setPost] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState(postData);

  // exclude column list from filter
  const excludeColumns = ["id", "videos"];

  // filter data by search value
  const filterData = (value) => {
    const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase().trim();
    if (lowercasedValue === "") setData(postData);
    else {
      const filteredData = postData.filter(item => {
        return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
          excludeColumns.includes(key) ? false : item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue)
        );
      });
      setData(filteredData);
    }
  }

  // handle change event of search input
  const handleChange = value => {   
    filterData(value);
  };

  return (
   
    <div>
       <Portfolio data={data} handleChange={handleChange}/>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the rendered Component i am mapping over the data:

```
 {data && data.map((post, index) => {
                                    return (
        <div>
             <p>{post.title}</p>
       </div>
   )
  })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're updating `postData` but then not doing anything with it.

I'd probably remove the  `const [postData, setPost] = useState();` and directly update `data` in your `useEffect`

So

```
useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "post"]{
      title,
      slug,
      style,
      thumbnail{
          asset->{
              url
          },
      },
      images[]{
          asset->{
            _id,
            url
          },
          alt
        },
      "categories": categories[]->title 
    }`)
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

I've also initialised `data` with an empty array... not required but good practice, helps anyone reading the code to know what's expected to be in that variable later on.

If this creates an issue with your filters, you can add another:

```
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   setFiltered(data);
}, [data]);
```

and then instead of referencing `data` when rendering, you can map through the `filtered` array. In this case you'll also need to update your filter function to update `filtered` instead of `data`.

Just in case I've muddied the water a bit, here is the completed code:

```
function App() {
   
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      sanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "post"]{
        title,
        slug,
        style,
        thumbnail{
            asset->{
                url
            },
        },
        images[]{
            asset->{
              _id,
              url
            },
            alt
          },
        "categories": categories[]->title 
      }`)
        .then((data) => setData(data))
        .catch(console.error);
    }, []);
  
    // Once data has been loaded, update filtered
    useEffect(() => {
       setFiltered(data);
    }, [data]);
  
    // exclude column list from filter
    const excludeColumns = ["id", "videos"];
  
    // filter data by search value
    const filterData = (value) => {
      const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase().trim();
      if (lowercasedValue === "") setFiltered(data);
      else {
        const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
          return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
            excludeColumns.includes(key) ? false : item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue)
          );
        });
        setFiltered(filteredData);
      }
    }
  
    // handle change event of search input
    const handleChange = value => {   
      filterData(value);
    };
  
    return (
     
      <div>
         <Portfolio data={filtered} handleChange={handleChange}/>
     </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default App;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the in-depth explanation!, But when i do as you mentioned (and also getting it right :) ) it actually works, except that it seems like filters are added on top of each other, e.g. i check one filter: 2 objects rendered, check another filter: only the object referencing both keywords is rendered...

Comment: Are you referencing `filtered`? `<Portfolio data={filtered} handleChange={handleChange}/>`

Comment: I've updated the code to make things a bit clearer 

Comment: yes exactly, but now as you posted the complete code i see where my mistake took place! i was using setData instead of setFiltered in the Filter function!
Thank you so much!! This tought me a lot!